# Warning : SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I know this question has been answered many time. I have seen the anwseres but still not able to understand what is going wrong. here the piece of code -

```
$var =$_POST['feature'];

    $status = 'passed';
    $allTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT SUM( IF( STATUS = :status, 1, 0 ) ) passed_count FROM tooldata WHERE testCase REGEXP :var GROUP BY family ORDER BY family' );
    $allTest->bindValue(":var", "^$var", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $allTest->execute(array(':status' => $status));

    while($row = $allTest->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        { 
        foreach($row as $key) 
            {
                $totalTestPassed[] = $key;
            } 
        }
            print_r($totalTestPassed);
```

I get this error on line - `$allTest->execute(array(':status' => $status));`

please guide me regarding why I am getting this error.

Comment: why you are using at the same time bindValue and array in your execute ?

Comment: @Svetlio why I can't use it like this ?

Comment: because nowhere you have seen such an approach before and no manual or tutorial has told you so?

Comment: thn how can I do this ?

Comment: $allTest->execute(array(':status' => $status, ':var' => '^$var'));

Comment: Use one of those methods.. all variables in execute(array) or bindValues 2 times for both vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$var =$_POST['feature'];

$status = 'passed';
$allTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT SUM( IF( STATUS = :status, 1, 0 ) ) passed_count FROM tooldata WHERE testCase REGEXP :var GROUP BY family ORDER BY family' );
$allTest->bindValue(":var", "^$var", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$allTest->bindValue(":status", $status); 
$allTest->execute();

while($row = $allTest->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{ 
foreach($row as $key) 
{
$totalTestPassed[] = $key;
} 
}
print_r($totalTestPassed);
```

you could also do away with the bindParam by doing this

```
$allTest->execute(array(':status' => $status, ':var' => ^$var));
```

Which will pass both as a string to the query by default, instead of defining it separately

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$status = 'passed';
$allTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT SUM( IF( STATUS = :status, 1, 0 ) ) passed_count FROM  tooldata WHERE testCase REGEXP :var GROUP BY family ORDER BY family' );
$allTest->bindValue(":var", $var, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$allTest->bindValue(":status", $status, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$allTest->execute();
```